# How to copy text from one textfield input to another using a BTN?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to copy text values from one textfield input to another. How can I do this?
I have created a js fiddle, which has a text form that once I click on edit details, another form will pop-up. In that new form, I want to be able to enter text in any of the textfields present and then once I hit save. The newly entered text will be moved/copied/transfered to the original textfields on the screen.

here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xsuh6pf7/2/

```
 <h1>Your Name and Address</h1>
    <form action="/">
      <div class="nameDiv">
        Name: <input type="textbox" name="firstname" title="name" id="name">

        <div class="dotOne"> ? </div>
        <span class="nameHelp"> Please enter first and last name   </span>

      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="addressDiv">
        Address: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="address">
        <div class="dotTwo">?</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="emailDiv">
        Email:
        <input type="text" name="Email" class="email">
        <span class="dotThree">?</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="numberDiv">
        Phone number:
        <input type="text" name="Phone number" class="number">
        <span class="dotFour">?</span>
      </div>
      <br>
    </form>
    <button class="btn" onclick="openForm()">Edit Details</button>

    <div id="container">
      <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Name', this, 'grey')" id="defaultOpen">Name</button>
      <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Address', this, 'grey')">Address</button>

      <div id="Name" class="tabcontent">

        <form>
          <div class="nameDiv">
            Title: <input type="text" name="firstname" title="name" class="name">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="addressDiv">
            Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="nameTransfer">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="emailDiv">
            Surname:
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="LastNameTransfer">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="numberDiv">
            Email Address:
            <input type="text" name="Phone number" class="number">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="numberDiv">
            Phone number:
            <input type="text" name="Phone number" class="number">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="save-btn" onclick="moveContent()">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="Address" class="tabcontent">
        <form>
          <div class="nameDiv">
            Line 1: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" title="name" class="name">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="addressDiv">
            Line 2: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" class="address">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="emailDiv">
            Suburb:
            <input type="text" name="Email" value="Email" class="email">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="numberDiv">
            State:
            <input type="text" name="Phone number" value="Phone number" class="number">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="numberDiv">
            Country:
            <input type="text" name="Phone number" value="Phone number" class="number">
          </div>
          <button class="save-btn" onclick="">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: Use `targetField.value = sourceField.value;`

Comment: doesnt work....

Answer (score 0):

You can use

document.getElementbyId("textfieldToTransfer").value = document.getElementbyId("textfieldOfData").value;

on the function of your button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue preventing other answers/comments from working for you (use of `document.getElementById()`) is that none of your `<input />` actually have the `id` attribute - just `name`, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" title="name" class="name">
```

You would either need to add `id="firstname"` so you could actually do:

```
document.getElementById("firstname").value = document.getElementById("firstnameTransfer").value
```

Or, you could use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the right `<input />` without adding the `id` attribute, e.g.:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='firstname']")
```

Comment: Ive added the following code --<script lang="javascript">

  document.getElementById("save-btn").addEventListener("click", moveContent);
function moveContent() {
    document.getElementById("name").value = document.getElementById("nameTransfer").value;
}​
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript, you can try adding

```
document.getElementById("name").onchange = function(){
    nameChange();
}

function nameChange(){
    document.getElementById("nameTransfer").value = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
```

This of course will only work for the name input.

Comment: I should mention that this won't do a live reload of the two input fields. The input value will appear in your transfer field after you click somewhere/do an action.

Comment: How do I make the value stay there?   this is the following code I have added ---            <script lang="javascript">

  document.getElementById("save-btn").addEventListener("click", moveContent);
function moveContent() {
    document.getElementById("name").value = document.getElementById("nameTransfer").value;
}​
  </script>

Comment: I'm assuming by "stay there" you mean how to make the changes of the transfer field appear on your original input field? What you have so far will probably do the trick, but like I said, regular old Javascript doesn't really have the capabilities to make the changes appear live. You might have to click somewhere else to make the changes appear.

Comment: I rewrote your code like so: 

document.getElementById("save-btn").onclick = function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 moveContent();
}

function moveContent(){
 document.getElementById("name").value = document.getElementById("nameTransfer").value
}

I would also get rid of the onclick="moveContent" in the HTML tag of btn

Comment: Why didnt my code work before?? Cannot I use addEventListener??

Comment: ALbert-- the how do I get rid of the pop-up once I have entered the text fields and hit save?? It needs to dissapear

Comment: I didn't test your code, but if didn't work, it's most likely because you didn't include the preventDefault for the event. Also, you're now asking about something completely different, and I'm not really doing you any favors here just giving you the answers. I suggest you look up tutorials for JavaScript events and DOM manipulation